# Cart page showing HTTP 500 Error and Not working

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, addtocart, http-error-500

I am using porto theme in magento 1.9.4.When user add products to cart then items added in cart but when user click to view cart or continue for checkout than gets 500 error. Any body know what might be the issue? Urgent Help needed! How to remove Http 500 error. Is it permission issue? Kindly Help
[image: that is the image]

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP 500 error means your server had an issue with the request, which means it threw an unhandled exception or you have a PHP fatal error somewhere. To get more details about what went wrong you should check your log files (<website_root>/var/log/), I would look at your system.log and/or exception.log files. You can also check your web servers error logs for PHP fatal error logs if the other two come up dry. The location of those logs depends on your websites configuration with whatever webserver you use. (For me at least I run a CentOS machine running httpd/apache and my website is configured to write logs to /var/logs/httpd/<site_name_error.log>)
Now if both of those come up dry, you might be having an issue with a file your website is trying to include. If that's the case you can edit <website_root>/lib/Varien/Autoload.php (~line 94 as of 1.9.4.5) and remove the `@` before `include`, the `@` symbol is a PHP construct to suppress warnings and will prevent logging if something fails to load. **Note**: **Make sure to remove that edit when you are done**, as editing core code is generally speaking a bad idea and this is strictly for debugging purposes.